# How to arrange React child components order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

With `react-semantic-ui`, I made a searchable, paginationable Table React Component

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/23q6vlywy

Usage

```
<PaginationTable
    items={[
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "test-item-1 ???"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "test-item-2"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "test-item-3"
      }
    ]}
    columnOption={[
      {
        header: "idHeader",
        cellValue: "id",
        onItemClick: item => {
          alert(item.id);
        },
        sortingField: "id"
      },
      {
        header: "Name~",
        cellValue: item =>
          `*custom text cannot be searched* property can item.name => ${
            item.name
          } `,
        onItemClick: item => {
          alert(item.name);
        },
        sortingField: "name"
      }
    ]}
    initSortingField={"id"}
    initSortingOrderAsc={false}
    pagination
    itemsPerPage={2}
    searchKeyProperties={["id", "name"]}
  />
```

But this component currently can only have a certain order

```
 1.SearchBar on top
 2.Table on middle
 3.PaginationBar on bottom
```

And actually, I didn't write 3 child components in the  Component, `SearchBar`, `Table`, `PaginationBar`

So it's hard for me to rewrite it to render props way to change the order such as below

```
<PaginationTable {...props}>
{({ SearchBar, Table, PaginationBar  })=>
<div>
     <SearchBar />
     <Table />
     <SearchBar />
    </PaginationTable>
</div>
</PaginationTable>
```

Because when I tried to change to render props, I first have to write 3 components independently, which means I have to change all variables under `this`( this.state, this.props, this.xxxFunction ) to something else.

For example:

In , I can use

```
 <Input onChange={()=>{
     this.setState({ searchBarText: e.target.value });
 }}/>
```

But If I change it to 3 components, I have to rewrite it to something like

```
const SearchBar = ({onTextChange}) => <Input onChange= 
    {onTextChange}/>

<SearchBar onTextChange={()=>{
    this.setState({
        searchBarText: e.target.value
    });
}} />
```

Is there any way I can adjust child components order elegantly or is there any way I can write render props easier?

**Updated @ 2018.10.27 17:36 +08:00**

I modified `<PaginationTable>`'s render function as below but it will be lost mouse cursor focus when typing on `<SearchInput>`

```
render(){
const SearchBar = ()= (<Input onChange={()=>{...} />);
const TableElement = ()=>(<Table {...} > ... </Table>);
const PaginationBar = ()=>(<Menu {...} > ... </Menu>);
enter code here
return(
<React.Fragment>
    {this.props.children({ SearchBar,TableElement, PaginationBar })} 
</React.Fragment>)};
```

Then I found out, in this way, DOM will update every time when my state updated because every render will make a new component reference by `const SearchBar = ()=>(...)`.

Thanks to @Ralph Najm

If I declare child component as below, DOM will not update every time.

```
render(){
    const SearchBar = (<input onChange={...} />);
    const TableElement = (<Table .../>);
    const PaginationBar = (<Menu .../>);
    //... same as above
}
```

In this way, I can change my component to render props in order to arrange the order very easily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include **all** necessary code (but minimal; [see this help page](/help/mcve)). In particular, we can't help you with what you're doing in `PaginationTable`'s `render` if you don't show us the `render` code.

Comment: What version of React? I ask because the solution may involve [fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactfragment), added in v16, and can be made more elegant in v16.2 and onward thanks to [improvements to fragments](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html).

Comment: Sorry about not sticking around after I posted. I'm using React 16.5. the render code is about 100 lines in the working example, I was thinking the question has been too long so I didn't make another minimal one. I will edit my question to a minimal one later. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PaginationTable component change your `render` function and before the return statement, assign the elements to variables (SearchBar, Table, PaginationBar, etc...) then just reference those variables in the render function.

I modified your example here https://codesandbox.io/s/vy4799zp45

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for contributing! Please have a look around, and read through the [help]. Questions and answers on SO must be **self-contained**. Include all relevant code changes within the text of the answer itself, not just as a link. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to fully understand the answer; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. (The OP's question has the same problem.)

Comment: Wow! I was doing it in a similar way but got completely different result. I made 3 real component in the <PaginatedTable> render function, such as `const SearchBar = ()=>(<Input ...  />)`; and return them as return (<React.Fragment> <SearchBar /> .... </React.Fragment>)
But in this way, after I typed text on SearchBar, i lost mouse foucs then I realized it made my dom updated every time. Thanks. I shouldn't change them to components. I should change them to  javascript variables only.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)